# Cannot get properties of javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop that adds properties to the data object

`words` is an array of strings

```
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  let word = words[i];
  data[word] = i;
}
```

After that, my objext looks like this:

```
data = {"the": 0, "of": 1, "and": 2, "to": 3, "a": 4, …};
```

I have tried

```
data['the'];
```

but it returns undefined

How do I retrieve the value of the property?

Here is my full code

```
let vocab = {};

$.ajax({
  url: "10000words.txt",
  success: function(data) {
    data = data.split(/\n/).slice(0, 10000);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let word = data[i];
      vocab[word] = i;
    }
    console.log(vocab['test']);
  }
});
```

When I type `vocab` into the console, it prints out vocab but when I try `vocab['the']` it returns undefined

Comment: `data['the']` works fine.  You're doing something else wrong.  Please provide an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You wouldn't be trying to do this in an async callback like a http request, would you?

Comment: before your loop, var data = {};

Comment: @Mark Meyer I add to the data object with an http request then I try `data['the']` but it is still undefined

Comment: if you do:`var data = { "the": 0, "of": 1, "and": 2, "to": 3, "a": 4};
            var result = data['the'];` you will see that it works fine. Maybe you miss some variable initialisation or something else.

Comment: @Marlon Assef that is what im doing

Comment: @MarkMeyer what is my issue?

Comment: Are you trying to access `vocab` outside the ajax function?

Comment: Yes, I have it declared outside the ajax

Comment: @bena The question was whether you’re trying to _access_ `vocab` outside the `success` callback, not whether you’ve declared it outside. Your issue is impossible to reproduce, if you didn’t actually access `vocab` outside of `success`. That’s why I think the most likely issue is this: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @Xufox, the call to console.log is in the callback.

Comment: @Kaiido Read the edited comment. It’s just the most likely scenario.

Comment: @Xufox The async function is not the issue

Comment: @bena The question is either a duplicate, or it’s caused by a typo. Again, the issue is impossible to be reproduced with the code you’ve shown. Try using `debugger`, try logging `vocab` by itself.

Comment: @bena Actually… try `console.log([...Object.keys(vocab).find((word) => /t[^a-z]*h[^a-z]*e/.test(word))]);` and see whether it matches `["t", "h", "e"]`. There may be invisible characters within your words, thus `vocab.the` won’t work.

Comment: Your words probably have trailing spaces.

Comment: @SLaks You are correct, thank you it works now

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to get a value by the object key.

```js
const words = ['Hello', 'world'];
const data = {};

for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  const word = words[i];
  data[word] = i;
}

const index = data['Hello'];

document.write(index);
```